# Read Email PHP POP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, imap, pop3

For my project i need to read Emails using `POP`

I am using the IMAP extension for PHP.

I do not need to fetch all the emails , but get emails by filtering `TO` and `FROM` .

it works with `FROM` not with `TO`

What i tried is

**(TO fetch all email `FROM` user@domain.com)**

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{pop.domain.net:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "username", "password")or die(imap_last_error());
$some   = imap_search($mbox, 'FROM "user@domain.com"',SE_UID);
imap_close($mbox);  
var_dump($some);
```

it works and i am getting an array .

**(To fetch all email that which send to user@domain.com using `TO`)**

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{pop.domain.net:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "username", "password")or die(imap_last_error());
    $some   = imap_search($mbox, 'TO "user@domain.com"',SE_UID);
    imap_close($mbox);  
    var_dump($some);
```

Whats wrong with me ? Please note that i am not specifying any mailbox name here ,for IMAP i need to mention the Mailbox name.

Please help me.

Comment: I tried to answer all most all my questions , It will be very helpful if you can answer the Question or commenting something about this.Thanks.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Does it throw an error? Or does it just return an empty array?

Comment: it return false , (sorry i though that its not necessary in case of this function )

Answer (score 0):

You may be searching the inbox for sent items, I think search only works within the root folder often referred to in the RFC spec as a mailbox...

The easiest way would be to switch mailboxes to search sent items (as most of the to's in your inbox should be your email unless you get CC's a lot and that opens up a whole other can of worms)

---

**Sources**
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-49